# Windows will erase permissions on files

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I have been seeing issues where Windows seems to "reset" permissions on files after I had set them. I have seen this in various versions of Windows. I'm sorry I don't have much more information. The files that are changing are sql DB files. Is there anything that would cause permissions to erase after adding them? I just recently seen this happen on win 7 pro x64. What will happen is i will set permissions on sql DB files. I set users and everyone to full control and domain users, network users, and everyone to full control on a domain enviorment. Later on down the road, those permissions i set are gone and the users and everyone groups i added do not show up as having permissions on the file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Unfortunately, it’s unlikely that anybody will be able to provide any useful answer if you can’t provide more information about your problem.  Please list at least some of the versions of Windows in which you have seen this problem.  When you say that permissions are erased/reset, do you mean everybody has all access or nobody has any access?  Has the file owner changed?  etc…

Comment: I just recently seen this happen on win 7 pro x64. What will happen is i will set permissions on sql DB files. I set users and everyone to full control and domain users, network users, and everyone to full control on a domain enviorment. Later on down the road, those permissions i set are gone and the users and everyone groups i added do not show up as having permissions on the file.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly, but, when you’re clarifying your question, it’s best to do it by ***editing the question*** (click on the “edit” below the question body).

Comment: It is likely that it is the software being used to manipulate the files that is doing this.